# Gravar dados de dois DataGridView no banco Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

Não estou conseguindo gravar os dados que estão em dois *dataGridView*, os dados que estão nos dois *DataGridView* estão em uma única Classe, tenho um código pronto porém serviria somente para um *DataGrid*, no mesmo `for` queria colocar outro *Grid* se possível, ou se tivesse outra forma de fazer isso,  ficaria agradecido pela ajuda.

```
 public void InserirItensOs()
    {
        try
        {
            if (DtGridServico.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < DtGridServico.Rows.Count - 1; i++) //quero colocar outro GridViews no for.
                {
                    DetalheOrdemServico ordem = new DetalheOrdemServico();
                    ordem.OrdemServicoId = Convert.ToInt32(DtGridServico.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                    ordem.NomeServico = DtGridServico.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    ordem.NomeMecanico = DtGridServico.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    ordem.VlrServDetalhe = Convert.ToDecimal(DtGridServico.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    ordem.ServicoId = Convert.ToInt32(DtGridServico.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);

                    context.detalheOrdemServicos.Add(ordem);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Terás que usar ou for para "ler" a outra datagrid.

Comment: BOM DIA AMIGO OBRIGADO PELA FORÇA, COLOQUEI OUTRO FOR COM O OUTRO DATAGRIDVIEW, POREM NA HORA DE SALVAR DAR CONFLITO DE IP DO PRODUTO, OQUE EU ESTOU FAZENDO E UMA TELA DE ORDEM DE SERVIÇO, ONDE UMA GRID EU COLOCO OS SERVIÇOS, E A OUTRA GRID EU COLOCO OS PRODUTOS E DEPOIS QUERO SALVAR AS DUAS GRID EM UMA TABELA NO SQL SERVER.

Comment: amigo eu consegui gravar os dados das duas DataGridView obrigado pela força.

Comment: @MecleudioQueiroz coloque a solução que foi utilizada, o código corrigido e explique também a lógica da solução para assim ajudar outras pessoas.